# Modal pop up not working on my website (Ubuntu VPS)

Tags: javascript, html, ubuntu, vps

So I uploaded files to my Ubuntu VPS and everything seems to work but when I press for example Chat Rules on my website nothing happens only the URL changes from

`http://website` to `http://website/?#chatrulesmodal`

but I get no pop up

```
<div class="modal" id="chatrulesmodal">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <h4>Chat Rules</h4>
        <ol>
          <li>No Begging.</li>
          <li>No Spamming.</li>
          <li>No Advertising.</li>
          <li>No Code Spamming.</li>
          <li>English ONLY.</li>
          <li>Always be polite, ESPECIALLY to mods and admins.</li>
          <li>No Coin Trading</li>
        </ol>
      </div>
    </div>

<div class="col s4 left-align"><input type="checkbox" id="mute" /><label for="mute">Mute</label></div><div class="col s4 center-align"><a href="#chatrulesmodal" class="center modal-trigger">Chat Rules</a></div><div class="col s4 right-align"><input type="checkbox" id="chatpause" /><label for="chatpause">Pause</label></div>
```

Also, if I want to login and terms should pop up it doesn't work either it shows `http://website/#tos-modal`.

Do I need any specific stuff installed on my ubuntu server to make it work?

Comment: This code is incomplete. There is no stylesheet, nor Javascript, both of which would be required for this to work.

Comment: @TomMettam i have all the javascripts in my js folder but i tihnk the problem is that im missing some packets maybe on my ubuntu server it seems like the javascripts arent being used?

Comment: Who knows? There is no way that I can know how you're expecting this to work, from the code you have posted.

Comment: I still don't see any code which is for modal dialogs

Comment: Please put a little effort into writing your posts. The first-person "I" is a capital letter, as has the first word of each sentence.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using Materialize.

Modal dialogs require more than just CSS alone.

At http://materializecss.com/modals.html you can see some code samples which show you how to set up the modal. In your case, the following JS should do the trick:

```
     <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                // the "href" attribute of .modal-trigger must specify the modal ID that wants to be triggered
                $('#chatrulesmodal').leanModal();
            });
     </script>
```

You also need to make sure that you include the Materialize javascript into your code.

```
<script src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i have tryed it but it doesnt work it seems like its not including my javascript files.. no idea why –